# Quick transfer specific file (Size >70MB) into two S3 buckets of different region?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to transfer a file whose size is greater than 70Mbs into two S3 buckets ( 1 - Our S3 bucket in same region and 2 - Client's S3 bucket in different region) of different region with minimum transfer time.

Following are the steps which I have implemented for the above requirement but it is taken too much time to transfer file specially in client's S3 bucket

1. I  have created two objects of S3 AWS, One with our access id and
   access    key and another is with client's access id and access key.
2. First I use our S3 AWS object to transfer file into our S3 bucket
   which is in same region through PUT Object function and it is not
   taking much time.
3. Then I use client's S3 AWS object to transfer
   file into client's S3 bucket which is in different region through
   PUT Object function and it is taking too much time.

I have also tried an alternate way to do the same is - first transfer file into our S3 bucket then transfer that file from our bucket to client's bucket through COPY Object function, but i found this process is also taking too much time.

So please help me out on this. I want to reduce the time taken to transfer the file into S3 bucket which is in different region.
And Yes I forget to mention that I am using **PHP** as a client so please provide solution in php.

Thank in advance, Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a chance that the client has enabled or will enable [S3 Transfer Acceleration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html) on the bucket?  This should improve the direct `PUT` request throughput (your code will need to change to take advantage of the feature).  Are you doing multipart uploads?  What is the region of the client bucket and the region of your EC2 instance, and how long does the direct upload take? How long does put+copy take?

Comment: Thanks Michael, for taking out your time and Yes I am doing multipart uploading, and my EC2 region is ap-southeast-1 and bucket region is eu-west-1. I have also tried COPY object function but it is also taking too much time. Please suggest me